# NameError: name 'pallet_centerx' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
if c == 1:  # pallet
    global pallet_center_x
    distancei = (2 * 31.4 * 180) * 5 / (width + height)
    plot_one_box(xyxy, im0, label=f'{distancei:.1f}cm', color=colors(c, True), line_thickness=2)
    # x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(xyxy)
    # Draw circle in the center of the bounding box
    pallet_x00 = int(x_top)  # + int(width / 2)
    pallet_y00 = int(y_top)  # + int(height/2)
    pallet_x01 = int(x_top + width)
    pallet_y10 = int(y_top + height)
    pallet_center_x = int((pallet_x01 + pallet_x00) / 2)
    pallet_center_y = int((pallet_y00 + pallet_y10) / 2)

if c == 2:  # pallet hole
    hole_x00 = int(x_top)  # + int(width / 2)
    hole_y00 = int(y_top)  # + int(height/2)
    hole_x01 = int(x_top + width)
    hole_y10 = int(y_top + height)
    hole_centre_x = int((hole_x01 + hole_x00) / 2)
    hole_centre_y = int((hole_y00 + hole_y10) / 2)
    if hole_centre_x < pallet_center_x:
        plot_one_box(xyxy, im0, label=label, color=colors(c, True), line_thickness=2)
        cv2.circle(im0, (hole_centre_x, hole_centre_y), 2, (0, 255, 0), -1)  # center-point

        # cv2.line(im0, (hole_centre_x, hole_centre_y), (pallet_center_x, pallet_center_y),
        #          (30, 255, 120), 1)
        # cv2.line(im0, (hole_centre_x, hole_centre_y), (hole_centre_x, pallet_y10),
        #          (30, 255, 120),
        #          1)
else:
    pass
```

I am working on extracting the coordinates of an object and contouring it using the yolo algorithm.

However, there is one problem.

That is, the pallet_center_x variable declared in if c==1: is not referenced in if c==2: .

The error contents are as follows.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/KH/0802_doosan_ligdevice/210809_orange_ws/orange+green_0809test_workspace.py", line 643, in <module>
    detect(**vars(opt))
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\torch\autograd\grad_mode.py", line 28, in decorate_context
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/KH/0802_doosan_ligdevice/210809_orange_ws/orange+green_0809test_workspace.py", line 509, in detect
    if hole_centre_x < pallet_center_x:
NameError: name 'pallet_center_x' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1
```

How do a variable declared within an if statement refer to another if statement?

The global variable also does not work. Let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You should define `pallet_center_x` before if else statment

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to use `global` to refer to a `variable`. The reason you're getting an error is that the `variable` `pallet_center_x` is being called before it gets defined so you should define `pallet_center_x` before calling it. Use None as a Placeholder `pallet_center_x = None`

```
pallet_center_x = None

c = 2
if c == 1:
    # lines of code
    pallet_center_x = 1
elif c == 2:
    if pallet_center_x == 1:
        pass
```